How do we add Content-Security-Policy on a coldfusion excel download page?
We have an excel export that worked a while back, but is not returning this error in the console when we try to access it via a button:
Mixed Content: The site at 'xxxxx' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'xxxxx' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS.

We have a file called view.cfm.  That view.cfm file has an onclick even that redirects to the export:
window.location = '/folder/export.cfm?ID=' + ID;

This export works perfectly fine if we hit the "export.cfm" URL directly.  We've had similar issues with normal cfm templates that we were able to resolve using this meta tag:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">

However, I've tried applying that tag in a variety of ways to this export file without success.  I even tried all the methods at once:
<cf_file action="readbinary" file="#fullfilepath#" variable="export_file">

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#filename#.xls">
<cfheader name="Content-Security-Policy" value="upgrade-insecure-requests">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
<cfhtmlhead text="<meta http-equiv=""Content-Security-Policy"" content=""upgrade-insecure-requests"">"></cfhtmlhead>

<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel" reset="true" variable="#toBinary(export_file)#">

How do we apply the Content-Security-Policy to a cfm file that's using cfheader and cfcontent to stream an xls file?

I think you need to serve all the request over https (including all redirects), and possibly from the same location.

You would not put that header in the response for the excel file because the browser doesn't load that file type like a web page so those headers don't apply. The content-security-policy header should be set in responses to web page requests along with that pages initial html response and is used by browsers to restrict what domains certain types of resources can be loaded from that web page. You can set your CSP and cross origin resource sharing (CORS) headers to restrict what domains the browser is allowed to load things like Ajax requests, images, css, javascript, etc.
